# How to extract one query at a time from an SQL file?

Tags: sql, bash, unix, awk, substr

I am trying to extract one query at a time from an SQL file.

This is what I have tried

```
index1=1
index2=1
while read -n1 char; do
if [[ $char == ";" ]]
  then
     SUBSTRING=$(awk 'substr($index1,$index2)' sql1Temp.sql)
     echo $SUBSTRING 
    index1=$index2
fi 
((index2+=1))

done <sql1Temp.sql
```

My SQL file look like this:

> sql1Temp.sql
>   select *from test1;
>   select *from test2;
>   select *from test3;

I am getting this as a result:

```
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./masterFile.sh
select *from test1; select *from test2; select *from test3;
select *from test1; select *from test2; select *from test3;
select *from test1; select *from test2; select *from test3;
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

Whereas I was expecting something like this:

```
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./masterFile.sh
select *from test1;
select *from test1;
select *from test1;
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

Also when I echo the $char inside while loop, it prints the file names every time $char gets the * from queries, select *from test1; etc

Something like this

```
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./masterFile.sh
s
e
l
e
c
t

masterFile.sh sql1result.sql sql1.sql sql1Temp.sql sql2.sql Untitled Document
f
r
o
m

t
e
s
t
1
select *from test1; select *from test2; select *from test3;
; 
same thing 3 times
```

In my opinion something is wrong with awk ?

Comment: Could you please explain what your script is intended for, as the way I read it, it seems like a convoluted and slow way of the equivalent of `cat sql1Temp.sql`, and I guess there has to be something I am missing.

Comment: I need to fetch one sql querry from a sql1Temp.sql file execute it  then copy this querry to a new file and remove that querry from original file.

Comment: Is there always a single SQL statement per line, or do you need to handle the case where you could have more than one (separated by a semi-colon)?

Comment: i would need seperated by ; .My sql file contain multiple lines query end with semicolon .the next querry start with a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is simply to read a file line by line, which can be done without `awk` and in a much simpler way :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line" # Or do what you need to do (e.g. execute SQL statement)
done <sql1Temp.sql
```

You do not need to worry about the semi-colon, as the `read` statement will read one line at a time, and there is one statement per line to be read.

If you want do remove successfully executed executed statements, you can do something like this :

```
local statements="sql1Temp.sql"
local failed="sql1Temp.sql.failed"
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if
    ! SOME_SQL_UTILITY "$line"
  then
    echo "$line" >>"$failed"
  fi
done <"$statements"
[[ ! -f "$failed" ]] || mv -f "$failed" "$statements"
```

Essentially, create a new file containing failed statements, and then move the new file to overwrite the old one unless the new file does not exist.

Please note that the `!` in `! SOME_SQL_UTILITY "$line"` means "consider failure of this command as meaning the test succeeds" (essentially a NOT logical operator).

Also, I have used `echo` in the code above to make it as familiar as possible, but using `printf` instead would make sure there is no special character sequence triggering unexpected shell behavior.  Replace the line above with this :

```
printf "%s" "$line" >>"$failed"
```

Finally, you could shorten the code a bit further by using a logical operator instead of an `if` block :

```
#!/bin/bash
local statements="sql1Temp.sql"
local failed="sql1Temp.sql.failed"
while IFS= read -r line; do
  SOME_SQL_UTILITY "$line" || printf "%s" "$line" >>"$failed"
done <"$statements"
[[ ! -f "$failed" ]] || mv -f "$failed" "$statements"
```

I also have included the "shebang" to allow this script to be launched as an executable.  Using a logical `||` (OR) operator is not better than using an `if` statement, do that only if you understand it well and like it better.

Comment: You should post that as a separate question.

Comment: how can i delete the $line(single querry) from sql1Temp.sql. after copying it to a new file

Comment: Do you expect `sql1Temp.sql` to be empty when you finish processing it, or will some of the lines remain in the file depending on some condition?

Comment: sql1Temp.sql will have the remaining sql querry which failed the execution